# RewriteRule to add missing parameter to URL Path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to use a RewriteRule to change an URL of the format

`http://server.com/srv/index.php/12345/somedynamichash/somedynamichash/somedynamichash`

where `/srv/index.php/12345/` is static to an URL of the format:

`http://server.com/srv/index.php/12345/XXXX/somedynamichash/somedynamichash/somedynamichash`

if and only if `XXXX` is missing in the request.

Neither this

```
RewriteRule "^/(srv/index\.php/\d+/)(?!XXXX(?:$|/))(.*)" "$1XXXX/$2" [R]
```

nor this combination

```
RewriteRule ^/srv/index\.php/(\d+)/(XXXX/.*)$ srv/index.php/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/srv/index\.php/(\d+)/(.*)$ srv/index.php/$1/XXXX/$2 [L]
```

worked.

Answer (score 1):

RewriteCond is the solution. It will apply the RewriteRule below only if the $1 does not match the XXXX:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "$1"    "!^XXXX$"
RewriteRule "^/srv/index.php/12345/([^/]+)/(.*)$" "http://localhost/srv/index.php/12345/XXXX/$1/$2"
```

Comment: No. Replacing the two occurrences of XXXX in the commands for whatever it really is should work.

Comment: I just realized that your first RewriteRule works for me. Did you enable mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should work for you in site root .htaccess or in Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(srv/index\.php/\d+)/(?!XXXX(?:/.*)?$)(.*)$ /$1/XXXX/$2 [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```